# Finding out closest date from today

Tags: xquery

I have defined $today = current system date.

Objective: To find out the value of closest "date" element from today and get the corresponding "price_per_share" value based on below xml. FYI, it does not matter whether the date is in past or in future when calculating the "closest date".

How do I do this?

I was thinking of

1. Calculating the difference between today and each "date" value
2. Then adding "difference" as the child of "details" for each "details" node
3. Then sort by the smallest "duration"
4. Then extract the first occurrence of "price_per_share" value.

But somehow adding a child does not seem to work for me either.

```
<test_record>
<details>
    <date>2013-01-16</date>
    <currency>USD</currency>        
    <shares>48</shares>
    <price_per_share>20</price_per_share>
</details>
<details>
    <date>2018-05-28</date>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <shares>49</shares>
    <price_per_share>30</price_per_share>
</details>
<details>
    <date>2018-10-25</date>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <shares>50</shares>
    <price_per_share>40</price_per_share>
</details>
<details>
    <date>2018-05-02</date>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <shares>51</shares>
    <price_per_share>60</price_per_share>
</details>
```

Can't use "map" as I am restricted to use xquery 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

The steps you describe sound good, except for the second one. There is no need to append anything as you don't actually want to modify the nodes. In fact, you can't do this with XQuery alone (XQuery Update is another specification which is intended for this). Also, there is no need to use a map here. Your logic sounds like you know procedural programming, but the concept of a functional programming language (XQuery being one) is quite different, so you might want to familiarize yourself with it.

Regarding you question: You first calculate the difference between the date and todays date. As you said it shouldn't matter whether this is in the past or the future, so we have to calculate the absolute value of the duration. To do this we first divide by seconds and thus get the number of seconds for this duration. As we now have a number we can get the absolute value in `$abs-diff`. We then order by this value, get the first element of the sequence and return `price_per_share`

```
let $today := fn:current-date()
return (
  for $detail in //details
  let $diff := xs:date($detail/date) - $today
  let $abs-diff := abs($diff div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S'))
  order by $abs-diff
  return $detail
)[1]/price_per_share
```

Comment: Thanks. When I tried above, it gives me below error: XQuery static error in #...yTimeDuration('PT1S')
) order#:
    Unknown constructor function: {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}dayTimeDuration

Comment: @user8748135, which XQuery implementation is that that your are using? the `xs:dayTimeDuration` data type and its constructor function should be part of any complete XQuery 1.0 implementation: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#types-predefined,https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#constructor-functions-for-xsd-types

Comment: I am using XQuisitor (a standalone tool to work on xquery) that uses saxon8.jar (which should support XQuery 1.0) and xquisitor-1.0a5.jar.

Comment: @user8748135 Is there any reason WHY you are using this seemingly terribly outdated tool, which seems not to be supported since 2005. I worked with XQuery for quite some time (and it is a small community) and this is the first time I am hearing this. Saxon 8 is also quite old. I really don't see any benefit in using this than compared to using BaseX or exist-db.